# Extract only first match using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string as follows:

```
course_name = "Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (PGCPRM) (Online)"
```

I want to extract only the 'PGCPRM' or whatever within the value within the first parenthesis and have a new course name as follows:

```
course_name_new = "Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (Online)"
```

Comment: `course_name_new = course_name.replace(' (PGCPRM)', '')` ?

Comment: @dmg No, I want to extract the value within the first parentheses whatever it is.

Comment: Then you should ask your question appropriately.

Comment: @dmg Sorry, I have updated this now.

Comment: So you need to extract the abbreviation that is within parenthesis, or whatever it is in the first parenthesis?

Comment: It looks to me like you want to **remove** the string (including the parentheses) within the first set of parentheses. Saying you want to **extract** it implies that you want to _save_ the string within the first parentheses.

Comment: @dmg It could be whatever (string).

Comment: @Iqbal so if it was "Blah (Online)" - does it become "Blah" - or remain the same as that's the only stuff between parenthesis?

Comment: and what about the space before the parenthesis?

Comment: @JonClements It becomes `Blah`

Comment: @dmg The space before parenthesis doesn't do anything.

Comment: So whether `"Blah (Something) (Online)"` becomes `"Blah__(Online)"` or `"Blah_(Online)"` (where "_" denotes space) is the same for you?

Comment: @dmg I got my answer. Thanks.

Comment: But your question is vague and poorly asked. SO is meant to be a searchable repository of good questions and good answers. Stop being selfish and fix your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
In [8]: course_name
Out[8]: 'Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (PGCPRM) (Online)'

In [9]: print re.sub('\([A-Z]+\)\s*', '', course_name)
Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (Online)

In [17]: print re.search('\(([A-Z]+)\)\s*', course_name).groups()[0]
PGCPRM
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.replace()` :

```
>>> course_name = "Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (PGCPRM) (Online)"
>>> course_name.replace('(PGCPRM) ','')
'Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (Online)'
```

edit: if you want to replace the word before `(Online)` you need regex and a [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\(\w+\) )(?=\(Online\))','',course_name)
'Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (Online)'
```

Or if you want to remove the first parentheses use following :

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\(\w+\) ).*?','',course_name)
'Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (Online)'
```

and for extract it use `re.search` :

```
>>> re.search(r'(\(.*?\))',course_name).group(0)
'(PGCPRM)'
```

Comment: No, I want to extract the value within the first parentheses whatever it is. Sorry for not mentioning that in the question. I will update this @kasra

Answer (score 1):

To extract value within first parenthesis

```
>>> course_name = "Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management (PGCPRM) (Online)"
>>> x = re.search(r'\(.*?\)',course_name).group()
>>> x
'(PGCPRM)'
```

And then to replace

```
>>> course_name.replace(x,'')
'Post Graduate Certificate Programme in Retail Management  (Online)'
```